# Wakeful Intent service not firing next day

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, intentservice, commonsware-cwac

https://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/2012/05/24/execute-service-once-a-day-when-internet-connection-is-available/comment-page-1/

I blindly follow this post which is based on commonware's wakeful intent service,but the service is never fired next day.I guess the problem lies on getMaxAge().
Below is the code of My dailY listener.

```
public class DailyListener implements AlarmListener {
    public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager mgr, PendingIntent pi, Context context) {

            // every day at scheduled time 
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           // if it's after or equal 9 am schedule for next day
           if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 9) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); 
            }
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

      mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        //mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),2 * 60 * 1000, pi);

    }

    public void sendWakefulWork(Context context) {


        if(Util.haveNetworkConnection(context))
        {

                Intent backgroundIntent = new Intent(context, PushLogDataService.class);
                WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, backgroundIntent);
            } else {
                Log.d("DailyListener", "We have no internet, enable ConnectivityReceiver!");

                // enable receiver to schedule update when internet is available!
                ConnectivityReceiver.enableReceiver(context);
            }
    }

    public long getMaxAge() {
        return (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + 60 * 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: `sendWakefulWork()` is not designed for a conditional. Also bear in mind that an inexact-repeating alarm may be inexact by an entire interval. Beyond that, use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see if your alarm is scheduled.

Comment: @CommonsWare that means I should not use inexactrepeating and before calling sendWakeful i am just checking network connectivity because Push service basically pushes data to a rest server.

Comment: "before calling sendWakeful i am just checking network connectivity because Push service basically pushes data to a rest server" -- IMHO, that needs to be part of the service itself. After all, you do not want to perform network I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: I am not doing any network fetch on the service ,from that push service I am calling an async task which is performing the http push,basically i need  a service that will push data everyday at a specific time on a daily basis.